# laravel aTob table relations

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.4, relationship

i'm making a web app in laravel 5.4 and i have some tables and some records like below.

evalution_to_member ( table )

```
id | evalution_id | member_id
--------------------------------
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 2
1 | 1 | 3
1 | 1 | 4
```

evalution ( table )

```
id | title
--------------------------------
1 | exam-1
```

members ( table )

```
id | name
--------------------------------
1 | member-1
2 | member-2
3 | member-3
4 | member-4
```

how can i access to members who belongs to evalution has id 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey in the evalution Model you should create this function `

```
public function members(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member');

}
```

App\Member us namespace of Member model
after this you can call Find Out All members like this

```
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Evalution;

Route::get('/findmembers/{id}',function($id){
   $evalution = Evalution::find($id);

   foreach($evalution->members as $member){
         echo $member."<br>";
   }
}
```

For inverse You can use this method too

Comment: member table does not include evalution_id column. did u read the question clearly? i think no . please read it clearly.

Comment: i read it clearly 
we have 3 table 

1 is for evalution
2 is for members
and 3 is for evalution_member

now we can call our third table in our function 


`return $this->belongsToMany('App\Members' , 'OurPivotTable')`

our Pivot Table in Your code is `evalution_to_member`

Comment: Nice ! Good luck  ;)